# Stanford CoreNLP lemmatization with predefined parts of speech

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

My purpose is to generate syntactic dependencies and lemmas while I have tokens with predefined parts of speech (POS). The problem is that I didn't find a way to pass POS to the CoreNLP pipeline. I can generate dependencies by passing POS tagged tokens to the standalone `LexicalizedParser`, as described in the [Stanford Parser FAQ](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.html#f), but how can I get the lemmas? I didn't find a standalone lemmatizer that accepts POS, nor a way to pass POS to the pipeline.

Comment: In the past I've looked for this but it doesn't appear possible through the CoreNLP server API.  I would think there should be a way if you're willing to hack into the java code.  You'd probably need to post to the Stanford CoreNLP page on Github for help on that.  You could also use a standalone lemmatizer such as [Lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) or use the lemmatizer from another NLP pipeline like [SpaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy),

Comment: @ bivouac0 Thanks for the response. Yes, I haven't looked at java code yet, I hope there is a solution, I tried only the command line api. I looked at other lemmatizers, but I hoped to solve all nlp tasks by a single library, if it's possible. Perhaps I will try to post on Github.